# Validate an XML file with schema but go through entire document and then present the errors?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I can validate an XML with a schema (XSD) but it stopps at the first error/fault and does not move on from there.
Is there a way to go through the entire XML file?

My guess at least, is the reading part, but can't find another to do this.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings)) 
{
        while (reader.Read()) { }
}
```

full code

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<string> errList = new();

    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        {
            errList.Add("WARNING: " + e.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            errList.Add("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlPath = @"path_here";
        string schemePath = @"path_here";

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new();

        // Need this for resolving include and import
        settings.Schemas.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

        // This might not be needed, I am using same settings to validate the input xml
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.Schemas.Add("namespace_name_here", schemePath);
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;
        settings.Schemas.Compile();


        // Create an XmlReader for the XML file
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings)) 
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { }
        }

        if (errList.Any()) 
        {
            foreach (string msg in errList) { Console.WriteLine(msg); }
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

--- EDIT ---

I'm using a large set of XSD's and there are imported right and left in other xsd's.
There are 22 XSD's in different namespaces =) and can't see a good way to include these here?
This is a link to the file at SFTI.se that contains the XSD's. https://sfti.se/download/18.3a0a1c2218723106f76484f0/1680520279996/Svefaktura1_Arkiv%202023-02-23.zip
Zip within the file: "XML-Schema för Svefaktura 1.0.zip"

There are exmaple XML files in the folder "SvefakturaExempelfiler"

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this with the C# XSD processor but I'll be happy to help if you're prepared to consider using the Saxon XSD processor.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I'm pretty sure the C# XmlReader and the default schema validator by default already does this. It will terminate on an exception, but continue on an XML schema validation error, which are treated as  2 different things.

Comment: If you're able to, providing a copy of the schema and the XML you're using would also help.

Comment: @mamift I've updated the original post with links and description to the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I morphed your code into a minimal but complete sample to reproduce the alleged failure to show multiple errors with a simple XML instance document and a simple XML schema:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
   private static List<string> errList = new();

    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        {
            errList.Add("WARNING: " + e.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            errList.Add("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<root>
          <item>a</item>
          <item>1</item>
          <item>b</item>
          <item>2</item>
        </root>";
        
        string xsd = @"<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
  <xs:element name=""root"">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name=""item"" type=""xs:decimal"" maxOccurs=""unbounded""/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>";

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new();

        // Need this for resolving include and import
        settings.Schemas.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

        // This might not be needed, I am using same settings to validate the input xml
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;
        settings.Schemas.Compile();


        // Create an XmlReader for the XML file
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings)) 
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { }
        }

        if (errList.Any()) 
        {
            foreach (string msg in errList) { Console.WriteLine(msg); }
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ERROR: The 'item' element is invalid - The value 'a' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:decimal' - The string 'a' is not a valid Decimal value.
ERROR: The 'item' element is invalid - The value 'b' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:decimal' - The string 'b' is not a valid Decimal value.
```

So both errors are found and reported.

Of course, as with any validation, if you have a completely wrong instance or element then there is often no way to recover from solely stating that first error.

Consider to show a sample of XML and XSD where your code fails to reproduce the errors you expect to allow us to judge whether it is possible.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that this would work with simpler files. this doesd not work with imported xsd in xsd's. I've updated my post to include the XSD and example XML that I'm using. There is a lot so could not copy-paste it here.

Comment: @HalSoul, I don't see why the code you posted fails with include and/or imports. I understand you are working with a complex schema set for which you have added a link in your question but I would think you should also able to add a minimal but complete XML instance sample to your question for which the code you posted fails to produce the errors you expect and how it fails, i.e. tell us exactly which errors you expect and which output you get instead. It is not our job to look to a zip of samples to figure which one is giving which problem exactly.

Comment: Import in the scheme works with my code, but if there are more then one error in the file, it only show the first. It seems to stop reading after it encounterns the first error.
You are correct though regarding the file.. I'm sorry. I'll try to test and publish smaller test file

Comment: I've created smal tests now and it seems that they work as intended... All errors in the XML is presentet. 
So then, there must be something strange with these the old XSD files, since these new once works without issues